# Oracle: Select a distinct column based on the value of a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what the current table looks like.

| item | description | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-001 | SIM CARD | 04/06/2021 |
| 12-001 | SIM CARD-1 | 04/07/2021 |

I want to get the latest distinct item from the above table. The record that I am trying to get will look like this since this record has the latest date.

| item | description | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-001 | SIM CARD-1 | 04/07/2021 |

I'm using Oracle. Below is my query. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT item , description, date FROM items
```

Comment: When a soccer match ends 3-3, that's called a "tie". Ties are always important when you talk about "first", "last" etc. Can two different descriptions be "tied" for "latest date" for the same item? Or is the pair (item, date) unique in your input data? If you don't have such unique constraints, you must always think about ties. In your example, what is the desired result, if the date in **both** rows was 04/07/2021 (and there were other rows with earlier dates for the same item, with various descriptions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want.

For example:

```
select item, description, date
from (
  select i.*,
    row_number() over(partition by item order by date desc) as rn
  from items i
) x
where rn = 1
```

In this case only the last row for every item will have the row number as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since your description column has different data so DISTINCT keyword would not work here. You may try below query with window function -

```
SELECT item , description, date
  FROM (SELECT item, description, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date DESC) RN
          FROM items)
 WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

On recent (12.x and greater) versions of Oracle you can use something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ITEMS
  ORDER BY "date" DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that `"date"` is quoted in this query because `date` is not a valid identifier in Oracle unless quoted, as it's also the name of a data type, the ANSI date specifier, and probably some other things I've forgotten.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d095504666595c83b791eb9f2d364b7)